# .inputrc key binding not working in PHP artisan tinker

Tags: bash

I am currently using GIT Bash on Windows 10 with custom key bindings in the `etc/.inputrc` file. This all works fine.

However when I am working with [Laravel "php artisan tinker" Shell](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-tinker), the key bindings no longer work. I don't know if it helps but it concerns ["Psy Shell v0.8.18 (PHP 7.2.0 — cli)](http://psysh.org/) by Justin Hileman". Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I am unsure what the expected behavior is here. Are you saying that you are trying to run  Laravel Tinker Shell/PsySH from Git Bash and you expect it to respect your `etc/.inputrc` keybindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.inputrc` is only used by the Readline library – it doesn't automatically apply to all terminal input.

PHP has a readline module available and it is supported by PsySh, so make sure you've installed and enabled it in `cli/php.ini`. ([Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/readline.installation.php) says it's Windows-compatible as of 7.1.0. [Relevant.](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/issues/177))

That said, it's also likely that a Windows-native PHP will be looking for inputrc in a different place than the MSYS-based Git Bash.

For programs which completely lack Readline support, there is a wrapper tool called `rlwrap` which adds those features. (Though of course it cannot provide app-specific tab-completion, only generic editing and history improvements.)